# Как настроить vue.config.js для proxy

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

Я получаю предупреждение в виде CORB Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type application/json. See  for more details.

Я работаю с api и хочу вывести фотки но он кидает мне это предупреждение

vuex где идет запрос

```
export default{
state: { 
    posts: [],
    perPage: 15,
    page: 1,
    total: 0,
    loading: false,
    s: []
},

getters: {
    numPages: state => Math.ceil( state.total / state.perPage ),
},

mutations: {
    updateLoading: ( state, loading ) => state.loading = loading,
    updatePosts: ( state, { posts, total, page } ) => Object.assign( state, { posts, total, page } ),
},

actions: {
    async fetchPosts( { commit, state }, page ) {
        commit('updateLoading', true)

        const params = router.currentRoute

        const start = ( page - 1 ) * state.perPage;

        const url = `/api/photos?${ params.name }=true&start=${ start }&limit=15`

        try {
            const response = await fetch( url, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', } } )

            const posts = await response.json()

            const total = posts.totalItems

            commit( 'updatePosts', { posts, total, page }) 
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e)
        }

        commit( 'updateLoading', false )
    },
}
```

}

vue.config.js тут настройка proxy

```
  devServer: {
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'http://gallery.dev.webant.ru',
    ws: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
  }
}
```

},

Я много чего перепробовал , но без успешно

Comment: На стороне **API** настройте **HEADERS** - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`, и т.д.

Comment: У меня нет доступа к серверу ; )

Comment: тогда запрашивай не из браузера